# How to add working sliders to map view in DJI-UXSDK-demo

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, uislider, dji-sdk

I want to add working UISliders as a subview to the map view of the DJI-iOS-UXSDK-demo (https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/iOS-UXSDKDemo). By "working" I just mean they should be freely draggable, right now they can only be moved in tiny steps to the right.

I tried adding the sliders using a .xib-View and just adding them programmatically. Both work fine for a generic MKMapView but not for the map view implemented in DJI-iOS-UXSDK-demo. I tried adjusting the frame sizes of the map view, the sliders and the .xib-view, but none of these changed anything for me.

To reproduce, please clone https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/iOS-UXSDKDemo and install the pods. Then add the following code to viewDidLoad in DefaultLayoutViewController.m after [super viewDidLoad]:

```
    //Get the map view instance and switch it into the main view
    MKMapView *mapView;
    if ([self.previewViewController respondsToSelector: @selector(mapWidget)]) {
        mapView = [[self.previewViewController valueForKey: @"mapWidget"] mapView];
        [self performSelector:@selector(previewViewTapped:) withObject:nil];
    };

    //Add the slider
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 50, 200, 10)];
    [mapView addSubview:slider];
```

You can ignore the registration error, as fixing that didn't change anything for me. The slider appears on the map view as expected, however it can only be dragged in small steps to the right. Adding a listener with addTarget:action:forControlEvents: also worked for me, however it is useless as long as the slider can't be dragged freely.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your reproduction steps, and was able to reproduce and also fix the issue.

I simply added the slider as a subview of the `DefaultLayoutViewController.m`'s view instead of a subview of the `MKMapView` and it starting to work smoothly.

```
//Get the map view instance and switch it into the main view
MKMapView *mapView;
if ([self.previewViewController respondsToSelector: @selector(mapWidget)]) {
    mapView = [[self.previewViewController valueForKey: @"mapWidget"] mapView];
    [self performSelector:@selector(previewViewTapped:) withObject:nil];
};

//Add the slider
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 50, 200, 10)];
[self.view addSubview:slider]; // <------ Add as a subview of the view controller and not the mapView
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, I should have noted that I've also tried this before. If you do it like this, the problem is, that the slider view will stay there even if you switch the map with the camera view by tapping on the preview in the bottom right corner. I want it to be only visible while the map is visible, so it should be attached to the mapview if possible.

Comment: @jan You can work around this by making the slider a property of the class and setting the `hidden` property of the `UISlider` to `YES` or `NO` appropriately. Ex: `self.slider.hidden = YES`. It's probably not ideal since you'll have to write a few extra lines of code to manage the slider alongside the map, but it will (should) work.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about doing that instead, however, I haven't found a fitting delegate to get notified when the views swap place. And I am not sure how to overwrite previewViewTapped: correctly or if it is even possible without making a personal branch of the pods which I was trying to avoid. Adding your own GestureRecognizer to rootView and pass touches manually to the respective ViewControllers should work, but I was hoping there would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it by adding my own UIPanGestureRecognizer to the slider with the target

```
- (void)sliderMoved:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if([recognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
        UISlider *slider = recognizer.view;
        slider.value = (slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue) * [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view].x / recognizer.view.frame.size.width + slider.minimumValue;

        //call the listener or just place your code here
        [self sliderChanged:slider];
    }
}
```

Doesn't solve the underlying problem, but this is what works best for me. I would still be interested in finding a fitting delegate for when the views change places if someone reading this happpens to know it.